# Why I get "No significate digits are available to display" in this example?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

V 8.0.4, windows 7.

As I was trying to see if I can get faster computation if I can get M to run in hardware single Precision (I do not know even if this is possible, I was trying things) I noticed that AbsoluteTiming returns 0 for just timing a `Pause` when I happen to make the Precision little less than double, but better than single:

Here is an example:

I restart the kernel, and type

```
r=AbsoluteTiming[Pause[2]]
{2.00111440000,Null}

Accuracy[r]

Out[26]= 11.438897913739035
```

Now I set M to double

```
 $MinPrecision=$MachinePrecision;
 $MaxPrecision=$MachinePrecision;
 r=AbsoluteTiming[Pause[2]]

 Out[32]= {2.001114400000000,Null}

 Accuracy[r]
 Out[33]= 15.653317853034773
```

No problem.

But when I do

```
 prec=Log[10,2]*29;
 $MaxPrecision=prec;
 $MinPrecision=prec;

 r=AbsoluteTiming[Pause[2]]

 Out[41]= {0.,Null}
```

You see, it is zero.

```
 Accuracy[r]
 Out[42]= 307.6526555685888
```

But I kept trying to see at where exactly it flips from zero to returning the actual seconds, and got this during one try

[image]

I know M uses Arbitrary Precision Numbers internally:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html

From the above link it says:

```
In doing calculations that degrade precision, it is possible 
to end up with numbers that have no significant digits at all
```

My question here is: Could someone explain this behaviour in this example? Why would measuring the timing of just a `Pause[]` require much more  precision than single precision? What exactly are the computation involved that it requires at least double to measure the `AbsoluteTime`?  Help says:

```
AbsoluteTiming is always accurate down to a granularity of $TimeUnit 
seconds, but on many systems is much more accurate.
```

and

```
In[22]:= $TimeUnit//N
Out[22]= 0.001
```

Actually my main purpose was just to see if I can make M run the computation using hardware single Precision  floating points, just to see if it will run faster. I read in a book that single Precision can be 2 times as fast as double, and was just trying to test that on something I have when I noticed this.

I currently run everything with the following at the top

```
$MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision;
$MaxPrecision = $MachinePrecision;
```

So that M runs using hardware double.

Thanks,
ps. and I checked this time the console before, I see no syntax errors.

Comment: Good question, I get the same behavior here too. Sadly I can't offer a sensible explanation. Your question seems to be well asked though.

Comment: You say "I know M uses Arbitrary Precision Numbers internally". That's not generally true. If you enter numbers like 1.0 mma will use machine precision numbers for which precision isn't tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think that setting `$MaxPrecision` and/or `$MachinePrecision` will have the effect that you desire.  Here's an example.

```
$MaxPrecision = $MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision;
result1 = Nest[4 # (1 - #) &, 0.123, 10^6]; // Timing
result2 = Nest[4 # (1 - #) &, SetPrecision[0.123, 
   $MinPrecision], 10^6]; // Timing
```

On my machine, the first computation takes 8 hundreths of a second, while the second computation takes nearly three seconds.  The reality is that the first computation is done in machine arithmetic, while the second is done in software arithmetic, that happens to have the same numerical precision.

I think that the easiest way to force machine arithmetic in Mathematica 8 is to use `Compile` with the `"CatchMachineOverflow"` and `"CatchMachineUnderflow"` set to `False`; or better yet just set `"RuntimeOptions"` to `"Speed"`.

Also, I think the reason you are getting 0 for your `AbsoluteTiming` command is that you have set the precision too low to represent the result.

Comment: The main reason I put the `$MaxPrecision = $MinPrecision = $MachinePrecision;` at the top of my cell is not really for performance (but if performance happens to be better when I do, I am not complaining), or to make M run in HW floats (I do not know if it does when I do that). But only so that I get the same numerical values to be able to compare results when I run the same computation/algorithm in Fortran or Matlab in double. This way I am looking at floating point numbers generated with the same Precision eliminating one variable from the investigation.